# Unix — run one script when wc of the file not matched

Tags: unix, ksh

I want to run the script with different parameters if the `wc` of the text file is matched or not matched!

My Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
x= echo `wc -l "/scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/yet_to_load.txt"`
if [ $x -gt 0 ]
then
sh /scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/eam.ksh /scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/vinu_mrdr_rpt.txt /scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/yet_to_load.txt from@from.com to.name@to.com
elif
sh /scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/eam.ksh /scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/vinu_mrdr_rpt.txt /scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/yet_to_load.txt from@from.com to.name@to.com, hi.name@hi.com
fi
```

Comment: Incidentally, your `elif` is missing its `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the output of `wc` accurately, and you need to avoid getting a file name in its output.  You have:

```
x= echo `wc -l "/scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/yet_to_load.txt"`
if [ $x -gt 0 ]
```

The space after the `=` is wrong.  The `echo` is not wanted.  You should use input redirection with `wc`.  (`wc` is a little peculiar. If you give it a file name to process, it includes the file name in the output; if you have it process standard input, it doesn't include a file name in the output.)  You should use `$(…)` in preference to back-quotes.

```
x=$(wc -l < "/scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/yet_to_load.txt")
if [ $x -gt 0 ]
```

If you want to check if the file is not empty (rather than being a file with data but no newlines), then you can use a more direct test:

```
if [ -s "/scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt/yet_to_load.txt" ]
```

You should probably be using a name such as

```
DIR="/scc/ftp/mrdr_rpt"
```

and then referencing it to reduce the ugly repetitions in your code:

```
if [ $x -gt 0 ]
then
    sh "$DIR/eam.ksh" "$DIR/vinu_mrdr_rpt.txt" "$DIR/yet_to_load.txt" \
        from@from.com to.name@to.com
else
    sh "$DIR/eam.ksh" "$DIR/vinu_mrdr_rpt.txt" "$DIR/yet_to_load.txt" \
        from@from.com to.name@to.com, hi.name@hi.com
fi
```

However, I think the comma in the second line is probably not needed, and it might be better to use:

```
who="from@from.com to.name@to.com"
if [ -s "$DIR/yet_to_load.txt" ]
then who="$who hi.name@hi.com"
fi

sh "$DIR/eam.ksh" "$DIR/vinu_mrdr_rpt.txt" "$DIR/yet_to_load.txt" $who
```

Then you've only one line with all the names in it.  And you might do even better with an array instead of string:

```
who=("from@from.com" "to.name@to.com")
if [ -s "$DIR/yet_to_load.txt" ]
then who+=("$who hi.name@hi.com" "Firstname Lastname <someone@example.com>")
fi

sh "$DIR/eam.ksh" "$DIR/vinu_mrdr_rpt.txt" "$DIR/yet_to_load.txt" "${who[@]}"
```

Using arrays means you can handle blanks in the names correctly where a simple string doesn't.